# How to redirect URLs with a specific IDs to new URLs on a new domain name?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, 301-redirect

I want to redirect all pages where there is a specific word inside in the URL. Both websites have the same articles.

For example:

`videos.example.com.ph/its-showtime-hashtags-hashtags-and-dawns-popular-dance-moves_966aaafd8.html`

should be redirected to

`example.com.ph/its-showtime-hashtags-hashtags-and-dawns-popular-dance-moves_8a4521384.html`

The difference is the Domain and the ID at the end. All articles with the URL `http://videos.example.com.ph` and the word `its-showtime` inside should be redirected to the same article on `http://example.com.ph/`

If this is too difficult, a redirect to `example.com.ph` mainpage would be ok too.

Comment: You can redirect a single URL of a known ID, but you can't do a _general_ redirect for "all articles" that have different IDs - if that is what you require? How do you map the source ID (eg. `966aaafd8`) to the target ID (eg. `8a4521384`)? Or is the redirect with a different ID just a "special case"?

Comment: the IDs are differnet but the url is the same. only teh domain and teh ID are different. The easierst way would be to redirect to the mainpage. I'm ok with this too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do a *simple* redirect of "all articles" if the source and destination IDs in the URL are different and there is no easy way to map between the two. For example, how do we know that `966aaafd8` maps to `8a4521384`?

In order to do this you would need to create a `RewriteMap` in your server config (containing all the source / destination IDs) or rewrite requests to another script that performs the lookup and then redirects.

However, you can redirect all requests to the document root on the other domain if that is OK. But this is generally a bad user experience (and hence bad for SEO), if that is a concern.

At the top of your .htaccess file in the `videos.example.com.ph` subdomain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =videos.example.com.ph [NC]
RewriteRule ^its-showtime http://example.com.ph/ [NC,R=302,L]
```

If the `videos.example.com.ph` subdomain and the main domain are physically hosted in at different places then you can remove the `RewriteCond` directive.

Note that this matches `its-showtime` at the start of the URL (as in your examples). If you need it to match *anywhere* in the URL, then just remove the `^` prefix.

Note also that this is a case-insensitive match (`NC` - `NOCASE`) - if this is not required then remove the `NC` flag from the `RewriteRule`. (The `NC` flag on the `RewriteCond` should remain, as this simply catches malformed requests that would otherwise still resolve.)

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK - assuming this should be a permanent redirect?

Comment: Just added but no result videos.showtime.com.ph/its-showtime-energetic-performance-from-its-showtime-family_2f1982c3c.html should be go to showtime.com.ph

Comment: Absolutely nothing happened? Just try entering `any gibberish` at the top of your .htaccess file. This should trigger a 500 Internal Server Error, however, if you still get nothing then your .htaccess file is not being processed.

Comment: I put it at the end and not at the top. Sorry my mistake. Works very well. Thank you

Comment: Can't tell you how many times I've tried looking up an old article on a news site and instead of responding with "404" or "301", the site just plops me either to "/notfound.404" or "/". WHAT IDIOT PROGRAMMED THIS!?"

Comment: Maybe some videos are not available anymore. We have to check this manually and this takes a lot of time because there are 6000 videos published. Sorry for this issue :)